# Unable to handle iFrame in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to access iFrame

```
    <iframe id="frame1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;" tabindex="100">
    <html>
    <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body id="tiny1" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.get('frame1').onLoad.dispatch();">
    <p/>
    </body>
    </html>
  </iframe>
```

And I want to `sendKeys()` to the body with `id=tinymce`. But when I tried to `switchTo().frame`, it does not work.

My Java code:

```
public void enterArea(String object, String content){
        String driverWindows = driver.toString();
        driver.switchTo().frame(selenium.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frame1']")));         
        String driverIFrame = driver.toString();
        WebElement contentTextArea = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 3))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='tiny1']/p")));
        contentTextArea.sendKeys(content);
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
```

The two `driverWindows` and `driverIFrame` always return the same string, it means the `web driver` has not switched, right?

Could you help me access to  elements? 
Please do let me know if require any further details.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `driver.getWindowHandle()` to see if the focus has switched to another window. This method returns a unique id for every frame.
2. Use `By.Id("frame1")` to locate by id, this is much cleaner than XPath.
3. Using `sendKeys` is equivalent to typing text on the keyboard. But you're sending this to a `<p>` element; as far as I know this will result is nothing. You need an editable control to type text into.

Answer (score 1):

Use `driver.switchTo().frame(frameName)`